# Redirect http and ssl requests on 50001, 50002 to localhost ports lighttpd

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

I have a http server running on `localhost:50001` and a ssl enabled server on `localhost:50002`, my root domain is say `example.com`  lighttpd serves a directory when example.com is requested. I need to forward `example.com:50001` and `example.com:50002` to `localhost:50001` and `localhost:50002`.

I am not able to achieve this, I tried config below

```
&HTTP["host"] == "example.com:50001" {
        proxy-core.backends = ("localhost:50001")
        }


$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/example.com"
        }
```

But that causes an error. I haven't tried configuring for ssl server.

Comment: The syntax you posted above appears to be for the unreleased and abandoned branch of lighttpd 1.5.  Please see https://wiki.lighttpd.net/ and https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy for lighttpd 1.4 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you should separate listener for localhost and external ip.

```
# in this config are only relevant parts listed
server.port = 50001
server.bind = "192.168.0.1"

$HTTP["host"] == "example.com:50001" {
    proxy-core.backends = ("localhost:50001")
    }

$SERVER["socket"] == "localhost:50001" {
    $HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
            server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/example.com"
    }
```

I think you are producing a loop with your config.